# Test if a sentence is in another sentence

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm trying to determine if a string is a subset of another string. A possible solution is given by `grepl` function. For example

```
X<-"hello"
Y<-"hel"
grepl(Y, X, fixed = TRUE)
```

returns `TRUE`. I would like to obtain a similar result also for sentences and not only for single words. In this case:

```
grepl("John Tolkien", "John Ronald Reuel Tolkien", fixed = TRUE)
grepl("Tolkien John", "John Ronald Reuel Tolkien", fixed = TRUE)
grepl("John Ronald Tolkien", "John Ronald Reuel Tolkien", fixed = TRUE)
```

return `FALSE`, but I would like to obtain `TRUE` because `John Tolkien`, `Tolkien John` and `John Ronald Tolkien` are subsets of `John Ronald Reuel Tolkien`

Comment: You could not get what you want due to `fixed=TRUE`, this disables regex functionality. So, what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```r
regex.escape <- function(string) {
  gsub("([][{}()+*^$|\\\\?.])", "\\\\\\1", string)
}
BuildRegex <- function(search) {
    x<-strsplit(search,"\\s+")
    paste0("^(?=.*(?<!\\w)", paste(regex.escape(unlist(x)), collapse="(?!\\w))(?=.*(?<!\\w)"), "(?!\\w))")
}
grepl(BuildRegex("John Tolkien"), "John Ronald Reuel Tolkien", perl=TRUE)
## => TRUE
grepl(BuildRegex("Tolkien John"), "John Ronald Reuel Tolkien", perl=TRUE)
## => TRUE
grepl(BuildRegex("John Ronald Tolkien"), "John Ronald Reuel Tolkien", perl=TRUE)
## => TRUE
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/NNA0cu).

The resulting regex is `^(?=.*(?<!\w)John(?!\w))(?=.*(?<!\w)Tolkien(?!\w))`:

- `^` - start of string location
- `(?=.*(?<!\w)John(?!\w))` - `John` as a whole word after any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?=.*(?<!\w)Tolkien(?!\w))` - `Tolkien` as a whole word after any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

If there are more than three words, there will be three lookaheads in the resulting regex.